# VMs on ESXi system, only able to use internal IPs

Tags: linux, networking, vmware-esxi, linux-networking

first off I am a bit of a network newb, I know the basics but that is about it.

So I have a ESXi server running a few VMs.

The set up is;
-Master IP (controls the ESXi box)
-Internet IP (for general use, accessing the net and VPN etc)
-Service IPs (several for use on hosting websites, these are publicly known)

On my ESXi box there are 2 networks.
-VM Network (Connects to the ESXi server NIC, Master IP and Internet IP are used directly with this)
-VM Local (Hosts the internal network, as well as Internet IP)

There is a DD-WRT router in a VM on both networks. It allows the VM Local network to access the internet via the VM Network using the Internet IP.

Confusing? Hope not

Now the VM Local network works fine, I have several machines on it that are internal only and external. They all use it to connect to the internet via the Public IP.

Problem is that the few machines that are also on the VM Network using the Service IPs are not responding on that network, only the internal VM Local network.

Here is a screenshot of the networking configuration.
http://i.gyazo.com/9a9c603eb138719453d9d06485581e8d.png

eth1 config file

```
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=5.xx.xx.207
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
BROADCAST=5.xx.xx.255
GATEWAY=94.xx.xx.254
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

70-persistent-net.rules config, the MAC address match the ones set in the VM settings, as well as the eth1 matching what the server host gave me to use (generated vMAC for VMWare)

```
# PCI device 0x8086:0x100f (e1000)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:29:10:85:23", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# PCI device 0x8086:0x100f (e1000)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:50:56:0a:81:fb", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

Any ideas on what I have done wrong?
I have been stuck like this for 2 days now and can't fine an answer :/

Thanks
Jack,

Comment: So I have tested with multiple Windows VMs and they work fine with this setup. So it is a Linux problem here not a network setup fail on my part, from the looks of it.

Comment: What adapters are you using in the hosts?

Comment: Using E1000s as I don't install the VMware tools for the others.

Comment: Try changing to vmxnet3, as per https://communities.vmware.com/message/2307363 it should be part of the linux kernel. Also, is that gateway in the same subnet? It looks wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your IP addressing:

```
IPADDR=5.xx.xx.207
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
BROADCAST=5.xx.xx.255
GATEWAY=94.xx.xx.254
```

You've configured a single /32 with that subnet mask, it's not able to route anywhere. Did you perhaps mean `NETMASK=255.255.255.0` which is a /24?

Even if that's right, the gateway is not in the subnet of the local IP. The communication to the gateway (and elsewhere within the local subnet) happens at Layer 2, and then the gateway is responsible for routing traffic with a destination outside the local subnet at Layer 3.

You need to configure a subnet which is a /29 or larger, and to use both a local IP address and a gateway within that subnet.

Also you don't need `BROADCAST`, the network scripts are smart enough to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks but I worked it out. OVH network is crap, the settings were correct it was a routing issue. Sadly their crappy network caused a problem whenever the server was on so they cancelled the server. Wont be using them again...